# Android: Check specify Imageview in specify LinearLayout after drag and drop

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering if there is a method, I can call to check if Check specify Imageview in specify LinearLayout after I drag and drop the ImageView into LinearLayout?

For example:

I have a Bicycle ImageView and I drop it into a Transport LinearLayout.

Is there any android java method I can check/call/use if the Bicycle ImageView is in the Transport LinearLayout after I drag and drop it in?

Comment: nop im doing an educational app where in the tutorial the student have to take an image and it is suppose to be drop in a container which is an LinearLayout. When the student want to submit the tutorial the application will check if the correct picture is inserted into the correct container